# Creating view data source on the fly in xpages

Tags: view, xpages, datasource

I need to create data sources dynamically and for this I followed the [article](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=449). However when trying to get the name of the variable related to the name of the view, an error is displayed reporting that the object in the case of the 'view1' article could not be found. It's as if the datasource has not been created, however if I put a print with the code data.getViewName(), the name of the view is returned correctly.
Anyone have any idea what it could be? Is there another way to create datasources from views? This article was written with version 8.5.3, I am using version 9.0.1 FP8, is there any incompatibility?

Comment: Article's XPage example does work for 9.0.1 FP7. Does this example work for you?

Comment: Does not work. Is there any alternative to building the datasource dynamically?

Comment: > I need to create data sources dynamically - Explain your use case, why you want it. There may be another approach.

Comment: I'm imaging a use case in which you allow the user to pick which data to view and it computes the view name based on the user choice, then displays the data from the chosen view. Fewer controls to access a variety of data.

Comment: My need is as follows, I have to search documents related to the document open to the user, on a history basis, I have to research the bases related to the last five years. These bases are created every semester, so I need to generate a datasource of the vision for each of these bases, for the last 5 years. Statically, ie setting the datasources at design time, I will have to change the application code each semester. Ideally, this code would be dynamic, that is, the datasources would be generated at runtime.

Comment: Please, update your question accordingly. And do specify - do you need single datasource (that means you show single grid of data) or need all (1-5)?